# facebook share, title not shared

Tags: facebook

Go to the following url 
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com&t=test%20title

The title is not shown in the shared message.

Am I using it correctly or is it a bug in facebook api.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that Google changes the Title attribute of the page via javascript. If you look at the source code of their search results page, the TITLE tags simply contain "Google".

Google doesn't do it, but if your page includes the "og:title" Open Graph metadata tag, Facebook will give that priority over your TITLE tags.

Comment: google is just an example, it is same for every other link I tried

Comment: Oh, if you're expecting the "t" paramater to work, don't. Facebook dropped it when they rolled out Open Graph, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Use this format:

[http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Hello+World&p[url]=http://www.google.com&p[images][0]=http://www.google.com/images/1.jpg&p[summary]=Awesome+Share](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=Hello%20World&p%5Burl%5D=http://www.google.com&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http://www.google.com/images/1.jpg&p%5Bsummary%5D=Awesome%20Share)

Use proper ASCII values for the escape characters if required.

Comment: Awesome! I never knew this. and this will work well for Flash sites!

Comment: @Rg90 but how could i use shared counter .?

Answer (score 0):

1. Mostly likely Google.com is already cached so your title will not appear even if the functionality is *still* working
2. It *seems* that facebook is ignoring the `t` parameter if a page `<title>` is present on the page you are sharing
3. Don't use the share button if you don't really need it, use the [Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) instead OR follow the instructions on the [`share`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) document (make use of **Basic Tags**).