# Facebook sharer,share image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I found a lot of posts, but none of them help me.

I want to share an image that is not visible.  Another issue is, when I click share, all images from the page are available for sharing. How can I fix it so that only images that I want to share are visible for sharing?

I have read this [Facebook Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), but that didn't help me.

Here is my function to create a share button :

```
function WP_fb_sharer($post) {

    $link = js_escape(get_permalink($post->ID));

    $button = '<a name="fb_share" type="box_count" share_url="' . $link . '" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>';

    $button = '
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 4px;">
    ' . $button . '
    </div>';
    return $button;
}
```

Is there any image size limit for Facebook?

Comment: this thing work <link rel="image_src" content="http://test.com/integration/facebook_post.jpg" /> and this not : <link rel="image_src" href="http://test.com/integration/facebook_post.jpg" /> href doesnt work but content does,I found a lot posts that suggest to use href.

Comment: do u simply want to share your stuff to social sites??like FB, twitter, is that so?? if yes, then goto addthis.com

Comment: i did the same work, some months back, like end users can share the product to the facebook etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863454/facebook-share-title-not-shared/4864018#4864018). Facebook was recommending the use of [Like Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) instead of the Share button, and I'm just checking and the *old* share document is now redirecting to the Like Plugin!

So just use the Like Plugin instead.

**EDIT:**
If you need to attached an image, just use the `og:image` meta tag and for videos use `og:video`. Check the "[*Attaching Audio and Video Data*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph)" section.

Comment: hmm,I need to use share,because I want on facebook profile page to show image or video.I think that that is impossible with like button.Thank you for response.

Comment: I try attaching image with like button,but no image is shown like with share button