# Facebook share with dynamic text

Tags: php, facebook, dynamic-text

I'm doing:

```
$fb = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=".$title."&u=".$url;
```

That line is inside a while loop getting results from database.
$url is always the same one but $title changes depending on the row.

Now I build the links and when I click them, they always show in my Wall the

```
<meta name="title" content=''>
```

text from my main page and not the $title text.

What can I do to fix this and share the text contained in $title?

Here the code I'm trying with og. After hitting the link the share text in my Wall is "Google" instead of what is in my variables:

```
<?php
$tt = "Some text in the meta";
    $url_p = "http://www.google.com";
        $url = urlencode($url_p);
        $text = "Text I want to show";
        $title = urlencode($text);
$fb = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=".$title."&u=".$url;
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $tt; ?>"/>

<a href="<?php echo $fb; ?>">share link</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook share, title not shared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863454/facebook-share-title-not-shared)

Comment: Check my answer in the above question.

Comment: I've edited my initial post, please see the code using the Google example. Am I aproaching it all right? Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one, is much better and you don´t have to use metatags:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=Title&p%5Bsummary%5D=Test%20Summary.&p%5Burl%5D=http://www.ideocentro.com/&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=https://static.e-junkie.com/sslpic/64332.ed95f53b41bc4885dd86e2b485f08a3b.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently possible via the sharer API if your url is 'always the same' and please include any relevant code since I cannot see how your, 'ine is inside a while loop getting results from database'.

Comment: I've added a random number at the end of the url so it is different everytime: http://mypage.com/folder/index.php?1451988335 being 1451988335 the number that changes but no advance :(

Answer (score 1):

How are you generating your meta tags? Are your trying to follow the [open graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)? If so, your 'name' should be 'og:title'.

Comment: I have my main's page meta tag, just one. That's where the sharer is taking the text from. The url links a perfecly formed:

Comment: www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?t=Text+from+database+belonging+to+row+id+1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmypage.com%2folder

Comment: but the sharer don't show in my Wall "Text from database belonging to row id 1" it shows what I have in my main's page meta tag. I'll try changing the url into a dynamic one also.